# How to edit the default validation message in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I have server validation below:

```
$this->validate([
    'first_name' => ['required','min:2','max:30',new PersonNameRule],
    'last_name' => ['required','min:2','max:30',new PersonNameRule],
    'username' => ['required','confirmed',new UsernameRule],
    'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6|max:20',
    'birthdate' => ['required','date',new EligibleAgeRule(21)]
]);
```

In front-end, I intentionally fail the validation and `console.log()` the errors. The log returned looks like below:
[image]

Now my question is, where is the **message** *(The given data was invalid)* came from? Can I customize it?

Comment: Better Use custom Request For these type of validation

Comment: If you want to do like this make sure you accepting 'application/json'

Comment: First U must check what rules failed, then -https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#custom-error-messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about your objective but if your finding the file. Its in the directory 
**..\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException.php**.

You can edit the message you mention inside the `__construct` method. See example below:

```
public function __construct($validator, $response = null, $errorBag = 'default') {
    parent::__construct('The given data was invalid.'); //change the message here

    $this->response = $response;
    $this->errorBag = $errorBag;
    $this->validator = $validator;
}
```

Comment: thanks it works! I would like to do some stuffs here that's why I ask.